# Get the data from previous month in sql query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a data of all the cost for each month. For example,

I have table of cost for each month

```
+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| Jan    | Feb    | Mar | Apr    | May    |
+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| 899.20 | 0      | 0   | 0      | 899.20 |
| 439.38 | 485.29 | 0   | 0      | 482.29 |
+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
```

Then what I want in the output for every month that is = '0', it will get the data in the previous month and so on until it's not equal = '0'

Is this possible using oracle sql or using xml.

I tried the oracle sql query below, for example is I want the value of April to be = `899.20`

I used the case when condition,

```
case 
    when Apr = '0' then Mar
    when Mar = '0' then Feb
    when Feb = '0' then Jan
    else Apr
end
```

and in XML is the if else condition

```
<?xdofx:if apr = '0' then mar
        else if mar = '0' then feb
        else if feb = '0' then jan
        else apr
end if?>
```

But both conditions I know didn't work. Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT Jan,
       CASE WHEN Feb > 0 THEN Feb
            ELSE Jan END
         AS Feb,
       CASE WHEN Mar > 0 THEN Mar
            WHEN Feb > 0 THEN Feb
            ELSE Jan END
         AS Mar,
       CASE WHEN Apr > 0 THEN Apr
            WHEN Mar > 0 THEN Mar
            WHEN Feb > 0 THEN Feb
            ELSE Jan END
         AS Apr,
       CASE WHEN May > 0 THEN May
            WHEN Apr > 0 THEN Apr
            WHEN Mar > 0 THEN Mar
            WHEN Feb > 0 THEN Feb
            ELSE Jan END
         AS May
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May ) AS
SELECT 899.20,   0,    0, 0, 899.20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 439.38, 485.29, 0, 0, 482.29 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>    JAN |    FEB |    MAR |    APR |    MAY
> -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----:
>  899.2 |  899.2 |  899.2 |  899.2 |  899.2
> 439.38 | 485.29 | 485.29 | 485.29 | 482.29
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5c309f47ac9fb9fc0c1af708f850044)*